# Reusing WebAPI Methods from one controller in another

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

What is the recommended design for reusing WebAPI methods from one WebAPI controller in another?

For example, suppose I have a `BooksController` that allows a book to be found using its title:

```
[RoutePrefix("Books")]
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    EntityModelContext db = new EntityModelContext();

    [Route("{title}")]
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(BookDto))]
    public IHttpActionResult FindByTitle(string title)
    {
        var book = this.db.Books
            .Select(b => new BookDto
            {
                 Id = b.BookId,
                 Title = b.Title,
                 Author = b.Author
            })
            .SingleOrDefault(b => b.Title == title);

        if(book == null)
        {
            return this.NotFound();
        }

        return this.Content(HttpStatusMessage.OK, book);
     }
}
```

e.g. You could find this book by accessing `/Books/Gone%20with%20the%20Wind`.

Now say I have a second controller that retrieves the chapters of the book if a valid book exists, e.g. `/Books/Gone%20%with%20the%20Wind/Chapters`.

I could just copy and paste the logic from the Books controller method into the BookChapters controller, and then add the additional logic of retrieving the list of chapters (I need to get the BookId in order to retrieve the list of chapters).  But this is not very DRY.

What I would like to do is call the BooksController.FindByTitle method from the BookChapters controller method, return if the response is not HttpStatusMessage.OK, or read the content (to get the BookId) and continue with the additional chapter logic if it is.  However this seems it would involve a pretty clunky solution since the method I am consuming returns an IHttpActionResult.  Is there an easier/cleaner way to do this?

Comment: what is the problem in moving this logic to a private function and call that function in both the controllers?